# wso2 IS - how to observe successful and failed login attempts at any IDP?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

My overall goal is to observe successful and failed login attempts when logging in via federal authenticator, but not working for local authenticator?

For my local authenticator, I wrote a custom secondary user store manager extending JDBCUserStoreManager, which is working fine. I wanted to observe the result of authentications. For this purpose I have registered a UserOperationEventListener in OSGi Container:

```
    ctxt.getBundleContext().registerService(UserOperationEventListener.class.getName(), new FcUserOperationEventListener(), null);
```

The implementation then is as follows:

```
public class FcUserOperationEventListener extends AbstractUserOperationEventListener {

    @Override
    public boolean doPostAuthenticate(final String userName, final boolean authenticated,
                                     final UserStoreManager userStoreManager) throws UserStoreException {

        LOGGER.info("Firecrest doPostAuthenticate is getting invoked...");
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, the #doPostAuthenticate method is never getting invoked when using the federal authenticator. Looking at AbstractUserStoreManager.java which invokes this listener in the #authenticate method I see code like:

```
if(!authenticated && !domainProvided && this.getSecondaryUserStoreManager() != null) {
    authenticated = ((AbstractUserStoreManager)this.getSecondaryUserStoreManager()).authenticate(userName, credential, domainProvided);
    return authenticated;
}
```

This looks like the listener isn't called for secondary user stores? Is this intended, or is this a coding error? My listener is definitely getting registered in OSGi. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be a crime just to log at the end of the doAuthenticate method in your custom user store manager.  At least it would cut down on the complexity for something small like this.

Put this at the end of your doAuthenticate method right before you return the result, then grep your logs from time to time or something:

```
if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    log.debug("User " + userName + " login attempt. Login success :: " + isAuthenticated);
}
```

With that you can set the log level on that class or package in the management console at will.

Comment: I want to login via federated authenticator and observe successful login attempts there at the secondary user store configured on a local authenticator. This listener isn't invoked in this case from logs. I might patch WSO2 IS to get this working for my custom deployment.